Customize displaying points in parts
can I change the way points are displayed in parts?
    %% Q Format
    %% ----------------------------------------------
        \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} (0--\thepoints) \hfill} 

        \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
        }
        \pointname{}
        \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}% Default is (\thepartno)
        
        
        \bonusqformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill}
    %% -----------------------------------------------

I'd like to have same as with questions after parts (0--\thepoints) as the way to print number of points.

have a look at the section 4.3.7 of the exam class documentation.
There is a \pointformat command that allows customization of how the points appear. Here is an example
\documentclass{exam}

  %% Q Format
    %% ----------------------------------------------
        \qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} (0--\thepoints) \hfill} 

        \renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
        \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
        }
        \pointname{}
        \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{(\thepartno)}}% Default is (\thepartno)
        
        \bonusqformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion .} \hfill}
    %% -----------------------------------------------

  %% Point Format
    %% ----------------------------------------------
        \pointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
        \bonuspointformat{(0--\thepoints)}
    %% -----------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
    \question[5] First short question
    \begin{parts}
        \part[2] first part;
        \part[3] Second longer part.
    \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}

I hope it is what you are looking for.

Yes, thats exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Do you know how can I change part label to have for example Question 1.1. (0--\thepoints) I know to use command: \renewcommand\partlabel{\textbf{Question \thequestion.\arabic{partno}.}}, but what should I do to make it exactly under the previous Question 1.?

@MichałSzymankiewicz I'm not sure what you mean. You should ask a new question and post an image (maybe written by hand?) to show waht you want.
